# {FieldError}Unsupported lookup 'time' for TimeField or join on the field not permitted

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, datetime, django-models

I am trying to do a query using Django but it does not work.

Here is my query :

```
Mytable.objects.filter(hour__time__range=(begin.time(), end.time()))
```

And I got this error :

```
{FieldError}Unsupported lookup 'time' for TimeField or join on the field not permitted.
```

where `begin = 2020-11-20 08:00:00` and `end = 2020-11-20 10:00:00`

I precise `hour = models.TimeField(default=None, blank=True)`

Could you help me please ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Should it be just `hour__range` perhaps?

```py
Mytable.objects.filter(hour__range=(begin.time(), end.time()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `hour` is, based on the error, a `timefield`, you can not make use of the `__time` lookup. You can simply work with a [**`__range`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#range) on the `hour` field:

```
Mytable.objects.filter(hour__range=(begin.time(), end.time()))
```

I would however strongly advise not to name a timefield `hour`, since it will only makes it more confusing. A field named `hour` suggest that this is an `IntegerField`. You can rename it for example to `starttime`, or `eventtime`.